# Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs' when running webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting this error when running the command below in order to run webpack dev server. While checking in some pages, most people mention it may be related to webpack outdated versions, but I believe my components are all on the most current version:

- webpack-dev-server@3.11.2
- webpack-cli@4.5.0
- webpack@5.24.4

This is the command I'm running to start the webpack dev server:

```
npx webpack-dev-server --compress --history-api-fallback --progress --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3005
```

This is my Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rcweb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "rcweb",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --compress --history-api-fallback --progress --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3005"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.24.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

This is the error Output:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- /home/user/dev/tests/reduxchat/rcweb/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason for this error, but worked around it by running `webpack serve`. Worked fine.